# How to mutate validators of fields in model serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use a `ModelSerializer` because it automatically add serializer fields.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'last_login', 'email', 'is_admin', 'password_expiry', 'is_active', 'created_timestamp',
                  'modified_timestamp')
```

It generates serializer like below.

```
UserSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    last_login = DateTimeField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    email = EmailField(label='Email address', max_length=255, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
    is_admin = BooleanField(required=False)
    password_expiry = DateTimeField(allow_null=True, required=False)
    is_active = BooleanField(required=False)
    created_timestamp = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    modified_timestamp = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

In that we can see that it automatically add a `UniqueValidator` to `email` filed.
So, If I do `serializer.is_valid()` it will perform field type validation for all fields and additionally `UniqueValidator` for email field.

That leads to a problem.

I have an API to find list of users by email id. For simplicity I used the existing serializer to dynamically create custom serializer.

```
CustomUserSerializer = UserSerializer
CustomUserSerialize.Meta.fields = ('email',)
```

Now, what I expect to perform is to validate only the email type but not `UniqueValidator`.

Please note that I don't wan't to have a separate serializer for this in my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **avoid the `UniqueValidator`** by specifying that `email` field as `email = serializers.EmailField()` in serializer as below,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField() # change is here <<<<
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'last_login', 'email', 'is_admin', 'password_expiry', 'is_active', 'created_timestamp',
                  'modified_timestamp')
```

**Update 1**

Then I would suggest you to use two different serializers for your operation, one is for `GET` and other is for `creation`. I'm assuming that you are using `ModelViewSet` class for your `view` So, you could override `get_serializer_class()` method to achieve the required result.

`serializer.py`

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'last_login', 'email', 'is_admin', 'password_expiry', 'is_active', 'created_timestamp', 'modified_timestamp')


class UserGetSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
```

preferred `views.py`

```
class UserAPIViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserGetSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all() 

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return UserCreateSerializer
        else:
            return UserGetSerializer  # other than "create"
```

Comment: If I do that it will perform unique validation when there is create request. In model email field is unique. I wan't to perform unique validation on create but not on get request.

Comment: DId you calling `is_valid()` while HTTP `GET` and creating a new instance?

Comment: yes, because I want to validate the email format to avoid unnecessary DB lookup.

Comment: @bkmagnetron I updated the answer. Please have a look

Comment: ya I thought exactly the same but it felt a little weird(or wrong) to have a separate serializer for get and create, also I haven't seen any examples doing like that on the internet. But, now I can proceed with that idea :).